# unable to push files to github - 403

Tags: github

So I just started off with github, I created two accounts to practice with.  One as myself and another as a different user to test pushing files.  This is a public repository.

So I'm able to push files with my account.

However when I use my 2ndary account and clone my repo and then try to push as a different user I get error 403.  I'm using https.

I just installed the lastest git from git-scm.

Answer (score 2):

In GitHub if you go to the repository settings and under the Collaborators section you should be able to add that second user. Reading that section it says that it allows push access to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 403 is "permission denied"; this clearly indicates you're either not authenticating with the right credentials, or the second user doesn't have push rights to that repo (which is the case unless you **explicitely** give the second user push rights).