# I setup a new GitHub account. Then I use the new GitHub account to build a new repository, but I can't push

Tags: git, github

```
remote: Permission to Coderlll/etstSSSSSH.git denied to oldGitHubAccount.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/newGitHubAccount/etstSSSSSH.git/':
The requested URL returned error: 403
```

The oldGitHubAccount is my first GitHub account.
 I use the account named oldGitHubAccount to update my old Github account is OK.

I have added the new SSH with the new email.
 What's the reason?
 How can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you added your old account to the collaborators list in the Github settings of your new repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to push files to github - 403](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275699/unable-to-push-files-to-github-403)

Comment: See also [403 error when pushing to github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308602/403-error-when-pushing-to-github)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

1. Either change your remote URL to use the SSH protocol with public / private key pair, then the stored credentials are obsolete for this repository
2. Make your credentials storing mechanism forget about the old account (git doesn't cache the credentials itself by default but it can delegate to other credentials storing mechanisms)
3. Give your old user push-rights by making it a collaborator in the new repository. The commits will still be attributed to your new account, if you used the right E-mail address when committing.

Answer (score 1):

Check you git configurations.

`git config --get user.name`
`git config --get user.email`

You must set it to your new account.

Also use git SSH protocol (git@) instead of the HTTPS, so it will use your SSH key.

Comment: Well, all of this is pretty wrong. `user.name` and `user.email` is only for creating commits it has no influence on pushing authorization and the git protocol (`git://...`) allows *only* fetching no pushing. What you mean is the ssh protocol (`git@...`). It should also work fine with HTTPS if he makes his credentials storer forget about the old account